# Spaghetti sinks

Tags: spaghetti

I have two brands of spaghetti, and I'm wondering if anyone can shed insight into which one of them has better quality.

I have been cooking a certain brand X of spaghetti for some time. When cooking, the noodles sort of float and play around near the top of the pot, making it easier for me to grab a piece and test for firmness. The resulting pasta water is pale or off-white.

On the other hand, another brand Z of spaghetti seems to be denser and sticks to the bottom during cooking. At the start, upon dumping into boiling water, the pasta softens/flexes much sooner than brand X. Finally, the resulting pasta water is more yellow in color. Because brand Z spaghetti sinks at the bottom of the deep pot, it has to be stirred constantly, to avoid overcooking and fusing of noodle strands.

As cooked, the Brand X spaghetti is thicker than Brand Z - both cooked to my own standard of al dente, around 9 minutes.

Without knowing the price of the two brands, would anyone be able to tell any tell-tale factors of quality for store bought spaghetti noodles?

Comment: Do they have the same ingredients listed on the packaging?

Comment: Are you sure brand X is actually real pasta? Spaghetti shouldn't float.

Comment: By what criteria do you measure quality?

Comment: Which one do you enjoy more?  Go with that one.

Comment: @mrog seems to have the only real criteria for that assessment. If Anthony Bourdain tells me Chicago style pizza is horrible, in his expert assessment, and it's my favorite kind, then that makes it the best, not horrible. For food I eat, my own opinion counts the more than any general consensus in the eating world.

Comment: @Stephie, I'll have to take a look at that. Just to be clear, these are factory, storebought pastas. Now that I think of it, maybe one of them doesn't use 00 flour?

Comment: @mrog, honestly I couldn't figure out. They definiely have differences to the bite. Okay, I'll give another clue. The one that soft of floats is cheaper, but also imported, so maybe there's some macroeconomic factors coming in.

Comment: @GdD, okay, so the one that sort of floats is cheaper than the one that sinks. However, it doesn't really float like buoy, but it's just more buoyant. It still has to be agitated with a tong so it doesn't fuse at the bottom of the pot (since I would cook consecutive packages of spaghetti by just adding water after every batch).

Comment: @rumtscho, I would say quality might lie in longer times before spoilage in the fridge, or less stickiness after cooking and cooling. Right now it's really hard to tell since it's just spaghetti meant to carry a very flavorful sauce.

Comment: @Stephie, let me retract that. On the package of the more buoyant pasta, it says "pasta di semola di grano duro" so I think that means semolina flour.

Comment: That just means durum wheat pasta @wearashirt . All pasta is made from durum wheat by definition, otherwise it's some other kind of noodle.

Comment: @GdD there is no single definition of the difference between pasta and noodle. Some people may go by the one you stated, others will have never heard of it.

Answer (score 1):

Are these fresh pastas or dried? That might explain the differences in cooking "behaviors"- however, I agree completely with mrog- I would just go with which ever one you like more.

Comment: Hello and welcome! I don't see how your post answers the question. We are a strict Q & A site, not a discussion forum. As a new user, we invite you to visit our Tour and Help pages. Both can be found under the 'help' dropdown at the top of the page.

Comment: My apologies, please delete the answer if necessary. I will pay more attention to answering the question directly in the future, thank you.

Comment: No apologies necessary. We welcome new users, especially those who are eager to help others. We also realize that we are a bit different than other sites, and that creates a bit of a learning curve. Our goal is to provide good quality answers that can be easily found. So again, welcome! We look forward to seeing more from you!

Comment: Hi @NavajoDreamchild. These are the dry, factory kind.